# How to reverse words one by one in c using pointers and arrays

Tags: c, pointers

Hey, yeah you guessed it homework. I am trying to print a string in reverse using pointers. Only the words though. So "hello world" is "olleh dlrow". 
What I'm doing in the code below is assigning one pointer(pSentence, which is a string array of multiple words passed down from the main function) to a temporary pointer until a space, then increment backwards and print the character from the temporary pointer to the beginning of the word, then do it again. I'm currently stuck, I don't know how to mark the beginning of the word and increment only to that. I know the while(pt != '0') is not the way to do it at all. The prompt says to store the word into a temporary string(tmpStrg) and use pT to point to it, so maybe I need to do something with tmpStrg? Any help is much appreciated and thank you in advance!!

```
void prtWords(char *pSentence)
{
    char tmpStrg[81], *pT=tmpStrg;
    int length=0;

    while(*pSentence != '\0')
    {
       while(*pSentence != ' ' && *pSentence != '/0')
       {
         *pT=*pSentence;
         pT++;
         pSentence++;
         length++;
       }
       pSentence++;

       while(length >= 0);
       {
         printf("%c", *pT);
         pT--;
         length--;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you use `x` for?  Anything?  I guess it's a leftover from a different idea. Regarding how to know when to stop... did you consider detemining the length of the word?  If you knew the length, you could figure out when to stop counting backwards, right?  re: The "prompt" and its suggestion for storing the word... you are doing that, by assigning `*pT`.  You are putting values into the thing `pT` points to, which is... `tmpString`.

Comment: Break the problem into pieces.  You need a routine to reverse a word.  You need to determine the beginning and end of a word (e.g. white space, eol, etc) to feed to the first routine.

Comment: Yes the x was left over sorry. Thank you for the idea, I tried that in the above code, but it didn't work, it compiles but nothing gets printed and it crashes, maybe I'm not doing what you ment or doing it wrong?  Also is pSentence++ a good way to make sure it skips the white space the next time the loop runs? And to duck, would white spaces work for the first time? something like while *p!=' '?

Comment: @Erik, what is `tmpString` array used for? You need to make a new string (NOT do change to the original)?

Comment: @ dante, correct because I'm actually going to reverse AND capitalize it (oooo complicated I know) but I still need to store the original string. But I know how to do the capitalizing part, I'm just stuck here.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `while(length >= 0);` is a mistake/typo (extra semicolon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void prtWords(char *pSentence)
{
    char tmpStrg[81], *pT=tmpStrg;
```

According to your code, I suppose here you use `tmpStrg[81]` as a new string for a word, and you print the word in reverse order later.

```
    int length=0;
    while(*pSentence != '\0')
    {
       while(*pSentence != ' ')
       {
```

Here is your problem for overflow, you should test `\0` and   at the same time (and change the second `while` to a `&&` with first `while` unchanged). There is no guarantee that a sentence will end with a .

```
         *pT=*pSentence;
         pT++;
         pSentence++;
         length++;
       }
       pSentence++;
       while(length >= 0);
```

When `length` is `0`, you should not do anything. Change to `>`.

```
       {
         printf("%c", *pT);
```

You should do `pT--` first, because last `pT++` does not have an assignment.

```
         pT--;
         length--;
       }
```

Here print a   when `*pSentence == ' '`.

```
    }
}
```

Work out the full code yourself as it is homework. Any further questions are welcomed.

Comment: This?    while(*pSentence != '\0')
 {

       while(*pSentence != ' ' && *pSentence != '/0')
        sorry I don't know how to comment in code I'll edit mine up in the original answer. But that still doesn't produce anything.

Comment: @Erik, and I have edited my answer, there are other points you have to change in your code.

Comment: @ Danta Jiang haha yes it is my homework, thats why I tried not to post something like hey do this for me, I was just stuck on that part. Also don't I need to run it to zero because isn't that where the pointer begins? I thought strings run until zero, and thanks for the tip on the printing a space, I actually need a \n but I would have for got if you didn't remind me.

Comment: @Erik, yes, the almost invisible check. Haha.

Comment: Oh wait I see, if I'm incrementing the pointer first it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Erik, I still think you should increment it **not** first. Otherwise, tempStrg[0] is wasted. Just move `pT--` before `printf`.

Comment: no I ment it doesn't matter that the string starts at zero, I was answering my above question, you can ignore it. So I've been doing some testing and it seems that everything is going fine but it won't even enter the second while loop, the while(length > 0) I can't figure out why though. I printed lenght at the end of the loop, it says five ( I used hello) which clearly is true in the while loop but it doesn't enter it.

Comment: Nevermind...I had a semi colon in the wrong spot. I finally got it though, thank you so much for all your help, I'm sure you have better things to do then help a college kid with his homework, I appreciate it greatly!!

Comment: Oh woops you told me that, I didn't refresh soon enough.

Answer (score 1):

@Duck's comment "Break the problem into pieces." was spot on, and highlights one of the most important design/programming techniques.

I'm not familiar with what unit testing frameworks are most often used for testing C code, but another good place to start is write some tests.

This code may not be exactly what you are looking for, as it performs its work in place:

```
void ReverseInPlace(char * pstart, char * pend)
{
    char tmp;

    while (pend > pstart)
    {
        tmp = *pstart;
        *pstart++ = *pend;
        *pend-- = tmp;
    }
}

void ReverseWordsInPlace(char *pSentence) 
{
    char * pstart;
    char * pend; 
    pstart = pSentence;

    while (*pstart != '\0')
    {
        // skip any (multiple) starting spaces
        while (*pstart == ' ')
        {
            pstart++;
        }

        pend = pstart;

        // find end of word (terminated by a space or end of string)
        while (*pend != ' ' && *pend != '\0')
        {
            pend++;
        }

        // check if anything left to do
        if (pstart >= pend - 1)
            return;

        ReverseInPlace(pstart, pend - 1);

        pstart = pend;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

char string1[] = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog";
char string2[] = "_";
char string3[] = " ";
char string4[] = " another";
char string5[] = "hello ";  
char string6[] = "";
char string7[] = "  ab";

 ReverseWordsInPlace(string1);
 ReverseWordsInPlace(string2);
 ReverseWordsInPlace(string3);
 ReverseWordsInPlace(string4);
 ReverseWordsInPlace(string5);
 ReverseWordsInPlace(string6);
 ReverseWordsInPlace(string7);

printf("%s\n", string1);
printf("%s\n", string2);
printf("%s\n", string3);
printf("%s\n", string4);
printf("%s\n", string5);    
printf("%s\n", string6);
printf("%s\n", string7);

return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but yes that is not what I was looking for. Thank you though!!